# Error: Timed out waiting for POP_ETW_EVENT_POWERTRANSITION_END event, events may have been dropped if the ETW buffers were too small

Tags: windows

while running pwrtest tool command "pwrtest /sleep /p:180 /s:3" gives error as

Error: Timed out waiting for POP_ETW_EVENT_POWERTRANSITION_END event, events may have been dropped if the ETW buffers were too small.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated

Comment: Please describle the context of the problem bit more: what API + language you are using etc?

Comment: Not using any api or language, while running this command "pwrtest /sleep /s:3"  in command prompt in admin mode- getting time out error

Comment: Just to Clarify further - I am using a tool "pwrtest" from Microsoft which helps to perform sleep/hibernate https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pwrtest-syntax